# AngularJS dynamic filter with expressions

Tags: angularjs

This is my HTML code. What I need to do is this filter.

```
ng-repeat="p in planes | filter : { 'tipo_planes' : {{tt.id_tipo}} }"
```

`{{tt.id_tipo}}` is an expression from another scope than `planes`. Its equivalent in `planes` is `'tipo_planes'`.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="tt in tipoPlanes">
    <div class="row collapse" id="collapse{{tt.id_tipo}}" data-parent="#plans">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 wow zoomIn plans" ng-repeat="p in planes | filter : {'tipo_planes' : {{tt.id_tipo}} }">
            <ul class="pricing-plan list-unstyled selected">
                <li class="pricing-title">{{p.nombre}}</li>
                <li class="pricing-price"><span ng-if="p.precio_t">{{p.precio_t}}</span></li>
                <li class="pricing-charac" ng-if="p.caracteristicas"><span>{{p.caracteristicas}}</span></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what's the problem/question?

Comment: @OmarEinea that my code is not working. I need to do what I tried to

Comment: I am guessing `tipo_planes` is a property inside `p` and `tt.id_tipo` is a value you want to filter. In that case remove the quotes and braces. The filter expression must be `filter:{ tipo_planes : tt.id_tipo }`

Comment: @gilango Yes, tipo_planes is a property of p. I've already tried that way. It doesn't work.

Comment: @gilango ooh, now I realized I didn't remove the quotes. Now it works! Thanks